# How to convert gas price in GWEI to USD or ETH?

Tags: gas, etherscan, gas-price, fees

I'm using Etherscan Gas Fee API to get current gas fees in GWEI. It can only return gas fee in GWEI and I tried to find online but can't find an answer on how to convert the Fee from GWEI to ETH or to USD. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on previous answer so I will just write here.
the 33 gwei value that your are getting is 'per gas' . so you need to multiply this value by the amount of gas your transaction will consume.
A basic ethereum transfer is 21 000 gas.
so : 21000 * 0.00009063351 = 1.9 usd approximately

Answer (score 0):

From [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#what-is-gas) docs -

> Gas prices are denoted in gwei, which itself is a denomination of ETH - each gwei is equal to 0.000000001 ETH

You can use the above to manually convert prices from gwei to ETH.

Additionally, can use any trusted source such as the [Etherscan API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/stats-1#get-ether-last-price) to find the latest ETH-USD price.

Comment: I tried it but that doesn't gives the current gas fee either in ETH or USD. For example, current gas fee on etherscan is 33 GWEI, if I used the above method, I get 0.00009063351 USD. But actually current network fees is 1.84 USD, so I guess I'm missing something here:/